# global variables in namespaces c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Im trying to define global shared pointer definition in a namspace such that every class in that namespace can use these. These pointers are defined in cpu_consts.h (cpu is the namespace). I know extern variables need to be defined outside of a function/namespace. This is done in cpu_class.cpp since this is the class that includes all the classes in the namespace. How do i predefine shared_ptr's?

The Register class is also in the cpu namespace.

I already tried predefining int's, which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cpu_class.h"

int cpu::yote;
namespace cpu {
...
}
```

cpu_consts

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


namespace cpu {
    class Registers;

    extern int yote;
    extern std::shared_ptr<Registers> registerPointer;
    extern Registers challas;
}
```

cpu_class.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cpu_class.h"

int cpu::yote;
... predefine shared_ptr how ?? Registers cpu::challas does not work
namespace cpu {
...
}
```

Comment: You would "predefine" them in an identical way. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `cpu::Registers cpu::challas` should do it. You need to tell the compiler that `Registers` is inside the namespace. Or put all that code inside the namespace instead of outside.